# ListView, BaseAdapter, getViewTypeCount() - How to force adapter to check again getViewTypeCount()?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, baseadapter

I'm using my own `BaseAdapter (standingsListAdapter)` for the `ListView (standingsLV)`.
When I set the Adapter:

```
standingsLV.setAdapter(standingsListAdapter);
```

`getViewTypeCount()` is called.
But later, when I set new data in adapter:

```
standingsListAdapter.setData(data);
```

where `setData(data)` after setting new data calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
public void setData(StandingsModelWrapper data) {
    groupsData.clear();
    if (data != null) {
        groupsData.addAll(data.getModel());
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

the method **getViewTypeCount()** isn't called again. Why?
**How to force adapter to check again getViewTypeCount()?**

---

Why do I need this?

- I display tables in every row of the list. Tables have different lenght (the number of rows).
- I want to set new data in the adapter so lenght of tables can change

That is why the number of my viewtypes should be recalculated every time new data comes to the list adapter.

Comment: I don't know for sure if this would work, but you can try calling setAdapter again with the same adapter.

Comment: `setAdapter` anyway will call `notifyDataSetChange()`, also will do some extra work... I would recommend you to use only that method, like @pietmau said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

Get `getViewTypeCount()` implementation is part of the **definition** of your adapter; it defines, regardless of what the actual data of the adapter is at any given moment, all the possible **types** of data it can hold.

`getViewTypeCount` is called by the framework to properly recycle list-item views that could be very different between different types of the data held by the adapter. When you change data in the adapter, views are still recycled according to the existing definition/implementation of the `getViewTypeCount`.

If you want a `getViewTypeCount` to be called again, create a brand new adapter and set this new one as your listview's adapter.

Comment: You've got it, mate. (Streets of Cambridge)

Comment: The  most simple solutions always the best :) Thanks Yami and Streets Of Boston. I also checked sources and getViewTypeCount() is called only once in setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) method in ListView class. So setting the adapter again is the only solution.

Comment: Note that setting the adapter again will cause the ListView to lose its current scroll position, etc. It is not very efficient either. If you know which types of items you can expect in your adapter data at any given time, you should code your getViewTypeCount to do so, having it anticipate all the types of data it can get.

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
standingsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: If you read my code again, you will see that I already call notifyDataSetChanged for my adapter. And it doesn't call getViewTypeCount().